# Howto retrieve a string field from sqlite3 db with swift

Tags: string, swift, sqlite

I am reading a table from a sqlite3 database. I managed to read an int field ( iEventYear in my code sample )
But I don't know howto read a string field from sqlite database.

I would like to use no additional library or framework, but the pure included sqlite3.h if possible.

Here's my code to demonstrate my problem:

```
 let sql = "SELECT year,title FROM historyevents";

    var statement:COpaquePointer = nil


    //var tail: CString = ""
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        println("Failed to prepare statement")
        exit(1)
    }else{

        while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {


                var iEventYear:Int16 = Int16(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));
//Howto retrieve a string ?
                var sEventTitle:String = String(sqlite3_column_xxxxxx(statement, 1)); 

            println(count);
        }

        println("query ok.");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve a String in this way.

```
let sEventTitle = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)))
```

However my advice is to use a SQLite wrapper, one of the most famous is [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), it's in 
Objective-C (obviously works well also in Swift), but if you prefer something completely in Swift, you can look at [SwiftSQLite](https://github.com/chrismsimpson/SwiftSQLite)

Comment: You can omit the explicit type parameter `<CChar>` because the compiler can infer it from the context.